# Дом с драконами. С прописной?

Tags: прописная

*Дом с драконами, в Симферополе.* Дом, на фасаде которого фигуры драконов.

Answer (score 1):

Этот известный дом в Симферополе, и он имеет **несколько названий**, которые пишутся по-разному: дом Чирахова, Дом с драконами, "Дом с драконами", дом "девяти драконов", "Драконий дом".

Кстати, "дома с драконами" есть и в других городах. Например, здание (в Томске), известное как «Дом с драконами», построено в 1910 году.